# Making navigation dynamic

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

i am trying to make my navigation dynamic but i' having a few problems. here is my code.

```html
<?php 
 if (stristr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], "index.php")) {
  echo '<li class="active">
    <a href="index.php">
        <span class="meta">
            <span class="text">HOME</span>
            <!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
        </span>
    </a>
</li>';
 } else{
  echo '<li>
    <a href="index.php">
        <span class="meta">
            <span class="text">HOME</span>
            <!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
        </span>
    </a>
</li>';
 }
?>
  
<?php 
 if (stristr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], "services.php")) {
  echo '<li class="dropdown active">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">
   <span class="meta">
            <span class="text">SERVICES</span>
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </span>
    </a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Service A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service D</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>';
 } else{
  echo '<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">
   <span class="meta">
            <span class="text">SERVICES</span>
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Service A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service C</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service D</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>';
 }
?>
   
<?php 
 if (stristr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], "data-catalog.php")) {
  echo '<li class="active">
  <a href="data-catalog.php">
        <span class="meta">
            <span class="text">DATA CATALOG</span>
            <!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
        </span>
    </a>
</li>';
 } else{
  echo '<li>
  <a href="data-catalog.php">
        <span class="meta">
            <span class="text">DATA CATALOG</span>
            <!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
        </span>
    </a>
</li>';
 }
?>
    
<?php 
 if (stristr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], "about.php")) {
  echo '<li class="active">
   <a href="about.php">
        <span class="meta">
            <span class="text">ABOUT US</span>
            <!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
        </span>
    </a>
</li>';
 } else{
  echo '<li>
   <a href="about.php">
        <span class="meta">
            <span class="text">ABOUT US</span>
            <!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
        </span>
    </a>
</li>';
 }
?>
   
<?php 
 if (stristr($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"], "contact.php")) {
  echo '<li class="active">
  <a href="contact.php">
        <span class="meta">
            <span class="text">CONTACT US</span>
            <!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
        </span>
    </a>
</li>';
 } else{
  echo '<li>
  <a href="contact.php">
        <span class="meta">
            <span class="text">CONTACT US</span>
            <!--<span class="caret"></span>-->
        </span>
    </a>
</li>';
 }
?>
```

After running, i realise that on the home page, the services list  drops down successfully but it doesnt do so when i'm on other pages. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code and its structure is perfect. There is nothing absolute wrong with the code. Just uploaded the files onto the web and everything is working perfect. I checked plugins and all and i realised that the file only needs to be on the internet to run smoothly.